# Why are my 0-arg and 2-arg GET methods resolved correctly, but not my 3-arg GET method?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, get, httpwebrequest

I can call my 0-arg GET method, and it works fine; the same goes for my two-arg GET method; when I add a third arg to the last one, though, the server returns "404 - not found". Why can it figure out, presumably based on the method definition (number and type of args passed), the proper routing in the first two cases, but not the last?

Here are the Web API Rest definitions, in the server app:

Repository Interface:

```
interface IInventoryItemRepository
{
    int Get();

    IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int CountToFetch);

    IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, string packSize, int CountToFetch);

    InventoryItem Add(InventoryItem item);
}
```

Repository Interface Implementation/concrete class:

```
public class InventoryItemRepository : IInventoryItemRepository
{
    private readonly List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = new List<InventoryItem>();

    public InventoryItemRepository()
    {
        string lastGoodId = string.Empty;
        string id = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=PlatypusBrain;Password=Platydude;Data Source=C:\XLWStuff\DATA\XLWDAT03.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\XLWWin\Data\abcd.mdw"))
            {
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
    . . .
                            Add(new InventoryItem
                            {
    . . .
                            });
                        } // while
. . .
    } // InventoryItemRepository (constructor)

    public int Get()
    {
        return inventoryItems.Count;
    }

    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.Id, ID)).Take(CountToFetch);
    }

    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> Get(string ID, string packSize, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.Id, ID)).Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.PackSize.ToString(), packSize)).Take(CountToFetch);
    }

    public InventoryItem Add(InventoryItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }
        inventoryItems.Add(item);
        return item;
    }       
}
```

Inventory Items Controller:

```
public class InventoryItemsController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IInventoryItemRepository inventoryItemsRepository = new InventoryItemRepository();

    public int GetCountOfInventoryItems()
    {
        return inventoryItemsRepository.Get();
    }

    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
    }

    public IEnumerable<InventoryItem> GetBatchOfInventoryItemsByStartingID(string ID, string packSize, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return inventoryItemsRepository.Get(ID, packSize, CountToFetch);
    }

}
```

...and the calls from the client app:

```
// 0-arg method (count)
private void buttonGetInvItemsCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelInvItemsCount.Text = string.Format("== {0}", getInvItemsCount());
}

private int getInvItemsCount()
{
    int recCount = 0;
    const string uri = "http://localhost:28642/api/InventoryItems";
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Int32.TryParse(s, out recCount);
        }
    }
    return recCount;
}

    // 2-arg method:
    string lastIDFetched = "0";
    const int RECORDS_TO_FETCH = 100;
    int recordsToFetch = getInvItemsCount();
    bool moreRecordsExist = recordsToFetch > 0;
    int totalRecordsFetched = 0;

    while (moreRecordsExist)
    {
        string formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}", lastIDFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri);
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);

                foreach (JObject obj in arr)
                {
                    var id = (string)obj["Id"];
                    lastIDFetched = id;
                    int packSize = (Int16)obj["PackSize"];
                    var description = (string)obj["Description"];
                    int dept = (Int16)obj["DeptSubdeptNumber"];
                    int subdept = (Int16)obj["InvSubdepartment"];
                    var vendorId = (string)obj["InventoryName"];
                    var vendorItem = (string)obj["VendorItemId"];
                    var avgCost = (Double)obj["Cost"];
                    var unitList = (Double)obj["ListPrice"];

                    inventoryItems.Add(new WebAPIClientUtils.InventoryItem
                    {
                        Id = id,
                        InventoryName = vendorId,
                        UPC_PLU = vendorId,
                        VendorItemId = vendorItem,
                        PackSize = packSize,
                        Description = description,
                        Quantity = 0.0,
                        Cost = avgCost,
                        Margin = (unitList - avgCost),
                        ListPrice = unitList,
                        DeptSubdeptNumber = dept,
                        InvSubdepartment = subdept
                    });
                } // foreach
            } // if ((webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (webResponse.ContentLength > 2))
        } // using HttpWebResponse
        int recordsFetched = WebAPIClientUtils.WriteRecordsToMockDatabase(inventoryItems, hs);
        label1.Text += string.Format("{0} records added to mock database at {1}; ", recordsFetched, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        totalRecordsFetched += recordsFetched;
        moreRecordsExist = (recordsToFetch > (totalRecordsFetched+1)); //  <-- I think recordsFetched will be a max of 269, instead of 270, so will have to fix that...
    } // while
    if (inventoryItems.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridViewGETResults.DataSource = inventoryItems;
    }
}

            // 3-arg method; the three differences between this and the 2-arg method above are commented.
            string lastIDFetched = "0";
            string lastPackSizeFetched = "1"; // <-- This is new/different from the 2-arg method
            const int RECORDS_TO_FETCH = 100;
            int recordsToFetch = getInvItemsCount();
            bool moreRecordsExist = recordsToFetch > 0;
            int totalRecordsFetched = 0;

            while (moreRecordsExist)
            {
// A third format arg is added, differening from the 2-arg method
                string formatargready_uri = string.Format("http://localhost:28642/api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}/{2}", lastIDFetched, lastPackSizeFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
                var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formatargready_uri);
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        var reader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
                        string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(s);

                        foreach (JObject obj in arr)
                        {
                            var id = (string)obj["Id"];
                            lastIDFetched = id;
                            int packSize = (Int16)obj["PackSize"];
                            lastPackSizeFetched = packSize.ToString(); // <-- this is the final difference in this method compared to the 2-arg method
    . . .
```

As you can see, there is very little difference between the two-arg method and the three-arg method; but the former works, and the latter doesn't. Why (not)?

### UPDATE

To answer Kiran Challa's comment/question below, here is what is in RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

...and WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithParameters",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}",
            //defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
            defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

I added this to WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWith3Parameters",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{packSize}/{CountToFetch}",
    defaults: new { ID = RouteParameter.Optional, packSize = RouteParameter.Optional, CountToFetch = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

...and it now works. Go figure; no decoration of the methods needed - maybe that's what was messing me up before, is I was trying to add both the decorations/annotations/attributes to the methods AND the entry into WebApiConfig.

I don't know, but until proven wrong, I'm going to steer clear of those much-ballyhooed attribute decorations.

Now I will test Tim S.'s suggestion regarding the 86ing of the optional bits ... works just dandy.

I reckon the "name" member of each MapHttpRoute in WebApiConfig.cs is simply an ID, and has no connection with anything else in the project? What I mean is, I could prove the one that is currently named "*DefaultApiWith3Parameters*" with a new name such as "*DuckbilledPlatypiOfThePondsUnite*" and it would make no difference.

Comment: can you share how your route configuration looks like?

Comment: I have done nothing with the route configuration; I had tested with that before, and never got it to do what I expected. It was working better by just leaving it be/blank, and it figured out what to call for the 0-arg and 2-arg methods. Now it's failing with 3, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route configuration states that `api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}` maps to `ID` and `CountToFetch`, but doesn't have anything saying that `api/InventoryItems/{0}/{1}/{2}` should map to `ID, packSize, CountToFetch`. Also, you probably don't really want to make any of these parameters completely optional. Try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWith2Parameters",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{CountToFetch}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWith3Parameters",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{ID}/{packSize}/{CountToFetch}"
);
```